# Can portable apps be damaging to the system?

Tags: portable, desktop-apps

To run portable applications do not need to have root rights. However, can they harm the system? For example, I heard that there are portable applications for Windows that cause crashes in the system. (Application led to a critical error and the blue screen of death). How things work in Linux? For example, in Ubuntu. Tell me please about it.

Comment: Portable apps? as in...?

Comment: For example, Tor browser.

Comment: In theory, all applications, scripts or whatever you run can cause harm to at least your own account. If it can do damage outside your own environment depends on what you allow it to do (mainly if you run it with sudo or not).

Answer (score 0):

By not using `sudo`, you protect most files outside your home folder from being written/removed, and sometimes, read. But remember that anything that's executable may cause harm to *you*. For instance, I could create a script that removes everything in your home directory without needing root permissions. Or I could create a script that reads your browser's configuration directory and sends me the contents.

As on Windows' BSOD issues, poorly written applications may crash on Ubuntu too, but I yet have to hear the first story where such an app without root permissions caused damage to the system.

The bottom line is: be careful with everything you download from outside the Ubuntu repositories.